# Javascript doesnt work in dropdown responsive menubar

Tags: navbar, responsive, menubar

Im a newbie in html, css, and javascript, currently Im trying to create responsive navigation bar, but for some reason the dropdown menubar wont show up when i clicked the menu button at 480px. I would be really thankful if someone could find the solution for this issue.

```js
$(function() {
  menu = $('nav ul');

  $('#openup').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    if (w > 480 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('responsive_navbar');
    }
  });

  $('nav li').on('click', function(e) {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w < 480) {
      menu.slideToggle();
    }
  });
  $('.open-menu').height($(window).height());
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url("http://i.cubeupload.com/NjsJx8.png");
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #eee;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

nav a#openup {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
  }
  nav {
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
    background: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    background: #444;
  }
  nav a#openup:after {
    content: "|||";
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 20px;
  }
  nav a#openup {
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive_navbar.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" href="js/responsive_navbar.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
  <nav class="cf">
    <ul class="open-menu">
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Item 0</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Item 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href='#' id='openup'>MENU</a>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery library file and fix typo(href -> src).

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive_navbar.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive_navbar.js"> </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

**EDIT**

```
<head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive_navbar.css">        
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive_navbar.js"> </script>        
</head>
```

Comment: i followed the instructions but still doesnt work, still couldnt open the dropdown menu :( im using brackets as code editor

Comment: @rybee17 : I edited answer. Include jquery library firstly.  I'm sorry for my mistake. Try this~

Comment: I already tried it, but unfortunately dropdown menu over pulled until the bottom of the page. I did refresh the page and then menubar displayed only less than one second and then the black layer covering the menubar. I dont know if this problem exists in your code editor, the problem would be clear if you dont mind to try the code again and see the newest problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your solution and click on manage Nuget Packages. There in update section update your jquery pacakage and then add that updated package's reference on page.

Comment: I followed the instruction already, but another problems shows up. The dropdown menu displayed only less than a second and the the black layers appeared and covering the dropdown menu. Ive been trying to edit and modify the codes for many times but the problem still exists. I am using brackets as my code editor.